# Why doesn't this purposely made invalid file positioning not bringing up any errors

Tags: c, file, positioning, binaryfiles, fseek

So given a binary file containing 100 bytes. I'm pretty sure that the INVALID ones should cause and error, but why doesn't it? I'm confused the once in INVALID should bring up a semantic error right? Or am I misunderstanding something

```
/* VALID */  fseek(fp, sizeof(char) * 2, SEEK_SET);
/* VALID */  fseek(fp, -2 * sizeof(char), SEEK_END);
/* INVALID */fseek(fp, sizeof(char)* 2, SEEK_END);
/* INVALID */fseek(fp, -2 * sizeof(char), SEEK_SET);
/* INVALID */fseek(fp, 50, SEEK_CUR);
/* VALID */  fseek(fp, -50, SEEK_CUR);
/* INVALID */ fseek(fp, 51, SEEK_CUR);
/* INVALID */ fseek(fp, -51, SEEK_CUR);
```

Comment: How are you checking for errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What "semantic error" are you talking about?

Invalid file position will cause `fseek` to fail, which will be indicated by the return value of `fseek`. You have to receive that value and analyze it to determine whether the function succeeded or not. Your code above completely ignores the return value of `fseek`.

Keep in mind that the standard library does not require all platforms to support `SEEK_END` positioning. The platform might not know where exactly the end of file is (until you actually bump into it while reading the file). For example, some file systems might not store the exact file size in bytes, but rather store how many "blocks" or "sectors" that file occupies, which can only serve as approximate file size. For this reason the language specification states that `SEEK_END` positioning is not guaranteed to be meaningfully supported.

Also keep in mind that one some platforms it might be perfectly allowable to seek past the end of file opened for writing. The subsequent write operation will write data at the new position, while filling the "gap" with zeros.

Comment: I thought it would crash or something. Just like assigning to access NULL.

Comment: @vincentbelkin: No, it does not crash. It simply quietly tells you "I can't do that" and does nothing.

Comment: why does this return 0 then? fseek(fp, sizeof(char)* 2, SEEK_END); Wouldn't it go past EOF?

Comment: @vincentbelkin: It might depend on implementation. If the file is opened for writing, it might be perfectly allowable to seek beyond the end of file. Once you write something there, the "gap" will be automatically filled with zeros.

Comment: Oh I see! So thats why, didn't realize that mattered before thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what sort of OS you are using (the fact that you say "binary file" suggests it's Windows), but on Unix-based systems the "seek" operation doesn't actually do anything immediately.  So it is not really likely to crash.

Here are some excerpts from the description of the **lseek** function, the core Unix function that **fseek** and friends use, according to *Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment* by W. Richard Stevens:

> Every open file has an associated "current file offset," normally a non-negative integer that measures the number of bytes from the beginning of the file.  Read and write operations normally start from the current file offset and cause the offset to be incremented...
>
> **lseek** only records the current file offset within the kernel -- it does not cause any I/O to take place.  This offset is then used by the next read or write operation.

In short, the thing that **fseek** changes is likely to be just an integer variable inside a struct.  Only when an actual I/O operation is requested does the Unix kernel access the file system.  So "impossible" positions won't cause a crash.